# KeyError when plotting a sliced pandas dataframe with datetimes

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

I get a KeyError when I try to plot a slice of a pandas DataFrame column with datetimes in it. Does anybody know what could cause this?

I managed to reproduce the error in a little self contained example (which you can also view here: http://nbviewer.ipython.org/3714142/):

```
import numpy as np
from pandas import DataFrame
import datetime
from pylab import *

test = DataFrame({'x' : [datetime.datetime(2012,9,10) + datetime.timedelta(n) for n in range(10)], 
                  'y' : range(10)})
```

Now if I plot:

```
plot(test['x'][0:5])
```

there is not problem, but when I plot:

```
plot(test['x'][5:10])
```

I get the KeyError below (and the error message is not very helpfull to me). This **only happens with datetime** columns, not with other columns (as far as I experienced). E.g. `plot(test['y'][5:10])` is not a problem.

Ther error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-aa076e3fc4e0> in <module>()
----> 1 plot(test['x'][5:10])

C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.pyc in plot(*args, **kwargs)
   2456         ax.hold(hold)
   2457     try:
-> 2458         ret = ax.plot(*args, **kwargs)
   2459         draw_if_interactive()
   2460     finally:

C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes.pyc in plot(self, *args, **kwargs)
   3846         lines = []
   3847 
-> 3848         for line in self._get_lines(*args, **kwargs):
   3849             self.add_line(line)
   3850             lines.append(line)

C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes.pyc in _grab_next_args(self, *args, **kwargs)
    321                 return
    322             if len(remaining) <= 3:
--> 323                 for seg in self._plot_args(remaining, kwargs):
    324                     yield seg
    325                 return

C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes.pyc in _plot_args(self, tup, kwargs)
    298             x = np.arange(y.shape[0], dtype=float)
    299 
--> 300         x, y = self._xy_from_xy(x, y)
    301 
    302         if self.command == 'plot':

C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes.pyc in _xy_from_xy(self, x, y)
    215         if self.axes.xaxis is not None and self.axes.yaxis is not None:
    216             bx = self.axes.xaxis.update_units(x)
--> 217             by = self.axes.yaxis.update_units(y)
    218 
    219             if self.command!='plot':

C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.pyc in update_units(self, data)
   1277         neednew = self.converter!=converter
   1278         self.converter = converter
-> 1279         default = self.converter.default_units(data, self)
   1280         #print 'update units: default=%s, units=%s'%(default, self.units)
   1281         if default is not None and self.units is None:

C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\dates.pyc in default_units(x, axis)
   1153         'Return the tzinfo instance of *x* or of its first element, or None'
   1154         try:
-> 1155             x = x[0]
   1156         except (TypeError, IndexError):
   1157             pass

C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.pyc in __getitem__(self, key)
    374     def __getitem__(self, key):
    375         try:
--> 376             return self.index.get_value(self, key)
    377         except InvalidIndexError:
    378             pass

C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\index.pyc in get_value(self, series, key)
    529         """
    530         try:
--> 531             return self._engine.get_value(series, key)
    532         except KeyError, e1:
    533             if len(self) > 0 and self.inferred_type == 'integer':

C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\_engines.pyd in pandas._engines.IndexEngine.get_value (pandas\src\engines.c:1479)()

C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\_engines.pyd in pandas._engines.IndexEngine.get_value (pandas\src\engines.c:1374)()

C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\_engines.pyd in pandas._engines.DictIndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\src\engines.c:2498)()

C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\_engines.pyd in pandas._engines.DictIndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\src\engines.c:2460)()

KeyError: 0
```

Comment: Pandas [bug report #4493](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/4493) and also [#6127](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/6127) seem to be about this issue.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

HYRY explained why you get the KeyError.
To plot with slices using matplotlib you can do:

```
In [157]: plot(test['x'][5:10].values)
Out[157]: [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0xc38348c>]

In [158]: plot(test['x'][5:10].reset_index(drop=True))
Out[158]: [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0xc37e3cc>]
```

x, y plotting in one go with 0.7.3

```
In [161]: test[5:10].set_index('x')['y'].plot()
Out[161]: <matplotlib.axes.AxesSubplot at 0xc48b1cc>
```

Comment: Thanks! But still, two questions remain: 1) Why is it only with the date column a problem (`plot(test['y'][5:10])` is not a problem)? Although `test['y'][5:10][0]` also does not work, as for 'x'. 2) I understand that with an integer index you cannot index based on location with the standard indexing tools (which was causing my confusion, but is explained here: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/indexing.html#advanced-indexing-with-integer-labels), but are there less standard tools that make this possible (something like an attribute `.ix` but based on the location eg `.ix_loc`)?

Comment: Stepping the trace in the case of date column, shows that matplotlib tries to do x[0] on the dates to retrieve tz info, which throws a KeyError. This is not done on y column. Pandas has location based indexing tools, but they are not used by matplotlib internals.

Comment: Ah OK, I see. What are the location based indexing tools (for integer labels)? I can't find them directly in the documentation.

Comment: I see it is a recent change (http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/whatsnew.html?highlight=irow#api-changes-to-integer-indexing). In the meantime, I have learnt to use the dates as the index so I don't have the problem anymore, but still, an annoying (but inevitable I suppose) consequence of the integer indexing (and dificult to see what you've done wrong as a newbie). Thanks again!

Answer (score 9):

Instead of calling `plot(test["x"][5:10])`, you can call the plot method of Series object:

```
test["x"][5:10].plot()
```

The reason: `test["x"][5:10]` is a Series object with integer index from 5 to 10. `plot()` try to get index 0 of it, that will cause error.

Comment: OK, thanks. And what if I want to plot x, y data? Like `plot(test['x'], test['y'])` with slicing.

Comment: I see the latest pandas (0.8.1) has the 'x' and 'y' keywords to do this (0.7.3, which I am using, not yet as far as I can see). But if I want to use my old native matplotlib functions and not pandas methods, there is no other way than first calling `np.asarray` before plotting?

Answer (score 4):

I encountered this error with `pd.groupby` in Pandas 0.14.0 and solved it with `df = df[df['col']!= 0].reset_index()`