# KeyError: 0L building boxplot

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, matplotlib

I'm using version 0.18.0 of pandas and 1.5.1 of matplotlib.

When attempting to create a boxplot, I receive **KeyError: 0L**.

```
df = df[(df['colA'] > 1000) & (df['colA'] < 5000)]
plt.boxplot(df['ColA'])
```

when I do not perform a filter on the `df`, the code runs and a boxplot is created without any issues.

When I use the filtered `df` to plot a histogram, this works without any errors.

```
plt.hist(df['ColA'], range(1000,5000,500))
```

What is causing the error when trying to create the boxplot? Any help appreciated.

Comment: I think it's a bug. I encountered a similar problem but I don't remember if it was about boxplot. matplotlib is looking for an index that starts at 0. A workaround would be: `df = df[(df['colA'] > 1000) & (df['colA'] < 5000)].reset_index(drop = True)` or `plt.boxplot(df['ColA'].values)`

Comment: Here's a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12406162/keyerror-when-plotting-a-sliced-pandas-dataframe-with-datetimes

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the workarounds and for linking the similar question. I will test the workarounds shortly and let you know how I get on.

Comment: Both work - thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In case you missed it while Googling (like I almost did), the answer is in the comments on the question:

- Use `.values`: `plt.boxplot(df['ColA'].values)`.
- Find more explanation and options in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12406162/keyerror-when-plotting-a-sliced-pandas-dataframe-with-datetimes).

  - **tldr;** Plot tries to go from index 0 onwards, which doesn't work for named columns or slices, etc... Using `.values` or reseting the index will solve this.

Kudos to @ayhan for this information.